# Invertible operators on a separable Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Using polar decomposition or Kuiper's theorem one can show that the set of invertible operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$ is a connected subset of ${\mathcal B}(H)$. But does anyone know an elementary proof?

Comment: "connected" with respect to what topology? $\;$

Comment: "connected" with respect to the topology induced by the operator norm

Comment: If an operator $A$ is invertible and $\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(A)$ has $0$ in its unbounded component, then the result is easy because $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}=I$. This is basically why a general proof requires a path that will perturb the spectrum until this happens. For a unitary $U$ with $\sigma(U)=\mathbb{T}$, there is a problem, and seems to require some kind of spectral result such as a logarithm.